# Beautiful soup double select?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="vl-article-title">

    <h3>
        <span style="font-size: 24px;">
            <a href="http://www.15min.lt/naujiena/sportas/fifa-2014/desimt-pasaul…onato-debiutantu-kurie-atkreips-jusu-demesi-813-430673?cf=vl"></a>
        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I need to get only links (a) but I don't know how. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
h3 = soup.select('div.vl-article-title > h3 > a')
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The > sign is the direct descendant selector.  It will not match the A element because there's a span in between.

You should be able to do this:

```
h3 = soup.select('div.vl-article-title > h3 > span > a')
```

Or, if it's OK to be a little less specific with the selector:

```
h3 = soup.select('div.vl-article-title a')
```

That matches all a elements which are undir the div with the class vl-article-title.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, been a while since I used beautiful soup, I mistakenly thought it worked with CSS selectors, but it does not.

One way to do this is:

```
a = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "vl-article-title"}).find("h3").find("span").find("a")
```

Comment: return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0

Comment: Oh, now it works for me either. However, it finds just firs one item ( there are mere than 20 links with the same structure).

Comment: Ok, then you'll have to use findAll instead and iterate over the results :-)

Comment: I am not that dumb :D I tried it already, here what I got: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: You can't use `.find` on a resultSet object. You have to do something like - if `res_set` is your `ResultSet` object, then you do: `for item in res_set: item.find("a").attrs["href"]`

Answer (score 0):

If that's the entire HTML, then you can simply do the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
link = soup.find("a").attrs["href"] # this gives you the link as a string
```

If there are multiple `<a>` tags in the page, you can replace the `find("a")` with `find_all("a")`, which returns an iterator.

**EDIT** per request, `<a>` tags being located within `<h3>` tag:

`link = soup.find("h3").find("a").attrs["href"]`

Comment: The problem is that it is not the entire html. In source are a lot of links but I need this one specific. That is inside of h3.